# What are the mechanics of coroutines in C++20?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, coroutine, c++20, c++-coroutine

I was trying to read the documentation (cppreference and the standard documentation on the feature itself) on the sequence of operations that get called when a coroutine function is called, suspended, resumed and terminated.  The documentation goes into depth outlining the various extension points that allow library developers to customize the behavior of their coroutine using library components.  At a high-level, this language feature seems to be extremely well thought out.

Unfortunately, I'm having a really hard time following the mechanics of coroutine execution and how I, as a library developer, can use the various extension points to customize execution of said coroutine. Or even where to start.

The following functions are in the set of new customization-points that I do not fully understand:

- `initial_suspend()`
- `return_void()`
- `return_value()`
- `await_ready()`
- `await_suspend()`
- `await_resume()`
- `final_suspend()`
- `unhandled_exception()`

Can someone describe in high-level psuedocode, the code that the compiler generates when running a user coroutine?  At a abstract level, I'm trying to figure out when functions like `await_suspend`, `await_resume`, `await_ready`, `await_transform`, `return_value`, etc are called, what purpose they serve and how I can use them to write coroutine libraries.

---

Not sure if this is off-topic, but some introductory resource here would be extremely helpful for the community in general.  Googling around and diving into library implementations like in cppcoro is not helping me move past this initial barrier :(

Comment: First result for me: https://lewissbaker.github.io/2018/09/05/understanding-the-promise-type (part 3 of an article) - is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: There is also this one: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines

Comment: @darune The former is helpful, especially in introducing the concept of these things. But it does not go into as much depth as the latter with the various options exposed by the TS, and the latter itself is not helping at the moment :(

Comment: @Curious: It's also important to understand that there have been some changes made between the TS and the core feature. Besides the keywords.

Comment: @NicolBolas Could you explain what you mean? Also, is the vote to close related to the question mixing these two? I ask because if so, I would want to modify the question appropriately. It's very important for me to understand this in depth, or at least get a good grasp on a resource, and the attempts I have made have mostly failed so far.

Comment: @Curious: "*Could you explain what you mean?*" I mean only what I said: that the TS is not *exactly* the same thing as the core feature. I don't agree with the "too broad" close vote, but you have to admit that asking for an explanation of the entire coroutine machinery is pretty big.

Comment: I see, makes sense, I guess I was asking about the accepted version of the TS, so the core feature sounds more appropriate. And yeah, I accept that this is a big question. And I don't expect to see any answer within the day or anything (obviously, the sooner the better). And I am planning on adding a big bounty to this later, just to justify the effort needed in an answer.

Comment: For the close votes, I do feel it's important to have a question like this answered somewhere where the community can freely edit things and come up with a good directed answer that can help people like me in the future understand things better. How can I edit this to make it less broad and off-topic?

Comment: "_too broad_" - Really? What's happening to good questions these days?

Answer (score 30):

[N4775](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/n4775.pdf) outlines the proposal for coroutines for C++20. It introduces an number of different ideas. The following is from my blog at https://dwcomputersolutions.net . More info can be found in my other posts.

Before we examine our whole Hello World coroutine program, go through the
various parts step-by-step. These include:

1. The coroutine Promise
2. The coroutine Context
3. The coroutine Future
4. The coroutine Handle
5. The coroutine itself
6. The subroutine that actually uses the coroutine

The entire file is included at the end of this
post.

### The Coroutine

```
Future f()
{
    co_return 42;
}
```

We instantiate our coroutine with

```
    Future myFuture = f();
```

This is a simple coroutine that just returns the value `42`. It is a coroutine
because it includes the keyword `co_return`. Any function that has the keywords
`co_await`, `co_return` or `co_yield` is a coroutine.

The first thing you will notice is that although we are returning an integer,
the coroutine return type is (a user defined) type Future. The reason is that
when we call our coroutine, we don't run the function right now, rather we
initialize an object which will eventually get us the value we are looking for
AKA our Future.

### Finding the Promised Type

When we instantiate our coroutine, the first thing the compiler does is find the
promise type that represents this particular type of coroutine.

We tell the compiler what promise type belongs to what coroutine function
signature by creating a template partial specialization for

```
template <typename R, typename P...>
struct coroutine_trait
{};
```

with a member called `promise_type` that defines our Promise Type

For our example we might want to use something like:

```
template<>
struct std::experimental::coroutines_v1::coroutine_traits<Future> {
    using promise_type = Promise;
};
```

Here we create a specialization of `coroutine_trait` specifies no parameters and
a return type `Future`, this exactly matches our coroutine function signature of
`Future f(void)`. `promise_type` is then the promise type which in our case is
the `struct Promise`.

Now are a user, we normally will not create our own `coroutine_trait`
specialization since the coroutine library provides a nice simple way to
specify the `promise_type` in the Future class itself. More on that later.

### The Coroutine Context

As mentioned in my previous post, because coroutines are suspend-able and
resume-able, local variables cannot always be stored in the stack. To store
non-stack-safe local variables, the compiler will allocate a Context object on
the heap. An instance of our Promise will be stored as well.

### The Promise, the Future and the Handle

Coroutines are mostly useless unless they are able to communicate with the
outside world. Our promise tells us how the coroutine should behave while our
future object allow other code to interact with the coroutine. The Promise and
Future then communicate with each-other via our coroutine handle.

### The Promise

A simple coroutine promise looks something like:

```
struct Promise 
{
    Promise() : val (-1), done (false) {}
    std::experimental::coroutines_v1::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
    std::experimental::coroutines_v1::suspend_always final_suspend() {
        this->done = true;
        return {}; 
    }
    Future get_return_object();
    void unhandled_exception() { abort(); }
    void return_value(int val) {
        this->val = val;
    }
    
    int val;
    bool done;    
};

Future Promise::get_return_object()
{
    return Future { Handle::from_promise(*this) };
}
```

As mentioned, the promise is allocate when the coroutine is instantiated and
exits for the entire lifetime of the coroutine.

Once done, the compiler calls `get_return_object` This user defined function is
then responsible for creating the Future object and returning it to the
coroutine instatiator.

In our instance, we want our Future to be able to communicate with our coroutine
so we create our Future with the handle for our coroutine. This will allow our
Future to access our Promise.

Once our coroutine is created, we need to know whether we want to start running
it immediately or whether we want it to remain suspended immediately. This is
done by calling the `Promise::initial_suspend()` function. This function returns
an Awaiter which we will look in another post.

In our case since we do want the function to start immediately, we call
`suspend_never`. If we suspended the function, we would need to start the
coroutine by calling the resume method on the handle.

We need to know what to do when the `co_return` operator is called in
the coroutine. This is done via the `return_value` function. In this case we
store the value in the Promise for later retrieval via the Future.

In the event of an exception we need to know what to do. This is done by the
`unhandled_exception` function. Since in our example, exceptions should not
occur, we just abort.

Finally, we need to know what to do before we destroy our coroutine. This is
done via the `final_suspend function` In this case, since we want to retrieve
the result so we return `suspend_always`. The coroutine must then be destroyed
via the coroutine handle `destroy` method. Otherwise, if we return
`suspend_never` the coroutine destroys itself as soon as it finishes running.

### The Handle

The handle give access to the coroutine as well as its promise. There are two
flavours, the void handle when we do not need to access the promise and the
coroutine handle with the promise type for when we need to access the promise.

```
template <typename _Promise = void>
class coroutine_handle;

template <>
class coroutine_handle<void> {
public:
    void operator()() { resume(); }
    //resumes a suspended coroutine
    void resume();
    //destroys a suspended coroutine
    void destroy();
    //determines whether the coroutine is finished
    bool done() const;
};

template <Promise>
class coroutine_handle : public coroutine_handle<void>
{
    //gets the promise from the handle
    Promise& promise() const;
    //gets the handle from the promise
    static coroutine_handle from_promise(Promise& promise) no_except;
};
```

### The Future

The future looks like this:

```
class [[nodiscard]] Future
{
public:
    explicit Future(Handle handle)
        : m_handle (handle) 
    {}
    ~Future() {
        if (m_handle) {
            m_handle.destroy();
        }
    }
    using promise_type = Promise;
    int operator()();
private:
    Handle m_handle;    
};

int Future::operator()()
{
    if (m_handle && m_handle.promise().done) {
        return m_handle.promise().val;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The Future object is responsible for abstracting the coroutine to the outside
world. We have a constructor that takes the handle from the promise as per the
promise's `get_return_object` implementation.

The destructor destroys the coroutine since in our case it is the future that
control's the promise's lifetime.

lastly we have the line:

```
using promise_type = Promise;
```

The C++ library saves us from implementing our own `coroutine_trait` as we did
above if we define our `promise_type` in the return class of the coroutine.

And there we have it. Our very first simple coroutine.

### Full Source

```
#include <experimental/coroutine>
#include <iostream>

struct Promise;
class Future;

using Handle = std::experimental::coroutines_v1::coroutine_handle<Promise>;

struct Promise 
{
    Promise() : val (-1), done (false) {}
    std::experimental::coroutines_v1::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
    std::experimental::coroutines_v1::suspend_always final_suspend() {
        this->done = true;
        return {}; 
    }
    Future get_return_object();
    void unhandled_exception() { abort(); }
    void return_value(int val) {
        this->val = val;
    }
    
    int val;
    bool done;    
};

class [[nodiscard]] Future
{
public:
    explicit Future(Handle handle)
        : m_handle (handle) 
    {}
    ~Future() {
        if (m_handle) {
            m_handle.destroy();
        }
    }
    using promise_type = Promise;
    int operator()();
private:
    Handle m_handle;    
};

Future Promise::get_return_object()
{
    return Future { Handle::from_promise(*this) };
}


int Future::operator()()
{
    if (m_handle && m_handle.promise().done) {
        return m_handle.promise().val;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

//The Co-routine
Future f()
{
    co_return 42;
}

int main()
{
    Future myFuture = f();
    std::cout << "The value of myFuture is " << myFuture() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

##Awaiters

The `co_await` operator allows us to suspend our coroutine and return control
back to the coroutine caller. This allows us to do other work while waiting our operation completes. When they do complete, we can resume them from
exactly where we left off.

There are several ways that the `co_await` operator will process the expression
on its right. For now, we will consider the simplest case and that is where our
`co_await` expression returns an Awaiter.

An Awaiter is a simple `struct` or `class` that implements the following
methods: `await_ready`, `await_suspend` and `await_resume`.

`bool await_ready() const {...}` simply returns whether we are ready to resume our
coroutine or whether we need to look at suspending our coroutine. Assuming
`await_ready` returns false. We proceed to running `await_suspend`

Several signatures are available for the `await_suspend` method. The simplest is `void await_suspend(coroutine_handle<> handle) {...}`. This is the handle for the
coroutine object that our `co_await` will suspend. Once this function completes,
control is returned back to caller of the coroutine object. It is this function
that is responsible for storing the coroutine handle for later so that our
coroutine does not stay suspended forever.

Once `handle.resume()` is called; `await_ready` returns false; or some other
mechanism resumes our coroutine,  the method `auto await_resume()` is called. The
return value from `await_resume` is the value that the `co_await` operator returns.
Sometimes it is impractical for *expr* in `co_await expr` to return an awaiter
as described above. If `expr` returns a class the class may provide its own
instance of `Awaiter operator co_await (...)` which will return the Awaiter.
Alternatively one can implement an `await_transform` method in our `promise_type` which will transform *expr* into an Awaiter.

Now that we have described Awaiter, I would like to point out that the
`initial_suspend` and `final_suspend` methods in our `promise_type` both return
Awaiters. The object `suspend_always` and `suspend_never` are trivial awaiters.
`suspend_always` returns true to `await_ready` and `suspend_never` returns
false. There is nothing stopping you from rolling out your own though.

If you are curious what a real life Awaiter looks like, take a look at [my
future object](https://gitlab.com/deus_ex_machina399/coroutine-async/blob/master/lib/include/async/Future.h).
It stores the coroutine handle in a lamda for later processing.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Because this topic is so important for me to understand properly, just to make sure I try my best to have the sort of participation I am hoping for, I'll be opening a bounty when the option opens and then selecting the accepted answer at the end.

Comment: My tutorials (which could not fit in SO) that explains coroutine mechanics with `co_await` in three parts: 
1. https://ggulgulia.medium.com/painless-c-coroutines-part-1-ba90dd101adb?sk=fad5c9d7985719e96583c999b51c8a1e
2. https://ggulgulia.medium.com/painless-coroutines-part2-29b36008b507?sk=6fa83a32164a2a043e6714d0e38886e5
3. https://ggulgulia.medium.com/painless-c-coroutine-part-3-536e4bce4f4f?sk=03a1bc6ad642b9398710397a2e7ac3fd

More to follow to explain coroutines with `co_yield` and `co_return`