# What is the actual implementation of co_await in c++20 co-routine

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++20, c++-coroutine

I am studying about coroutines in C++20.

I try to understand how the co_await works.

Is any implementation of co_await.

Reading ,co_wait seems to have the behavior of future/promise.

When a function/object is called with co_wait inside a thread, something like this is called

```
auto promise = std::promise<std::string>();
auto future = promise.get_future();
void sleep()
{
     std::cout << future.get() << std::endl;
}
```

When notify is called, another thread calls something like this

```
void wakeup()
{
     promise.set_value("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: [cppreference's doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines#co_await).

Comment: I have provided a detailed answer in the link below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57621168/what-are-the-mechanics-of-coroutines-in-c20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example `TYPE a = co_await awaitable(args)`, 
It seems like to be expanded in this way:

```
    {
        auto && tmp = awaitable(args);
        if (!tmp.await_ready())
        {
            tmp.await_suspend(*this);
        }
        ret = tmp.await_resume();
    };
```